# CString output parameters from a clr function

Tags: c#, clr

I have a function

```
int func(CString InputParm1, CString InputParm2, 
         CString *OutputParm1, CString *OutputParm2)
```

Now I call that from

```
int DDManaged::func(String ^InputParm1, String ^InputParm2,
                    String ^OuputParm1, String ^OutputParm2)
```

Input variables pass in fine.  Output variables I have an issue going from the `CString` result to the `OutputParm1` for example.

How would I do that?

The answer posted is different because it is going from System::String^ to CString.  My software does that for the input just fine.  My issue is getting the output string back out of the clr function to the c# code.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can printf(OutputParm1) in the CLR but the caller never sees the value, so I am not prototyping my function such that my c# program sees the value...any ideas on what i might be going wrong?

Comment: I found the issue in my case.  The console.writeline was incorrect.